# How to schedule SQL-Agent to run a maintenance plan every x minutes?

Tags: powershell, sql-server

My name is aSkywalker and I am an involuntary DBA.

I have done some research, and would like to back up transaction logs every 10 minutes.

I have written some powershell scripts to compress, encrypt and shuffle the files around.  I have created a maintenance plan to backup the Transaction log, then run the powershell script. (thanks to some great help from serverfault and stackoverflow!)

Now, I can see how to schedule it daily at a specific time. I can create subplans and schedule  away.  But I don't see a simple way to say 'every 10 minutes', and I don't want to start manually creating 144 subplans.  Or do I have to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using SQL Server Management Studio to schedule this as a SQL Agent job?

When you're setting the job's job schedule properties, use the "Occurs Every" radio option in the Daily Frequency section. Change it to every 10 minutes with a start time of midnight and an end time of 11:59 PM. That ought to do what you're after.